# How to plot an equation with no analytical solution (no closed form solutions)

Tags: graphing-functions, closed-form, python

Consider the following equation:
$$y-\ln{y}=F(x,k) \ \ \ \ \ \ x,y,k \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $F$ is a non linear real function of $x$ and a constant $k$, that we know. Suppose that we want to use *python*, lets say with the standard module *matplotlib*, to plot $y$ as a function of $x$; to do this we would like to find an analytical expression for $y(x)$ (or maybe it's better to say a closed-form expression for $y(x)$, I am not really familiar with the terminology), **problem is:** there is no way to express $y(x)$ in a closed form.

The question now is: how can I plot the solutions to this equation?

My first instinct is to improvise, with *python*, some sort of search algorithm: we pick an arbitrary value for $x=x_0$, we find $F(x_0,k)$ and then we implement a search algorithm to find what value of $y$, once plugged into the left side, gives $F(x_0,k)$. We now have a point of the graph! We now interate the procedure, we find multiple points, and then connect the dots; and we get our plot. **Does this procedure have a name? Is there a better, or more standard, way to make a plot of this? If my procedure is the better one: is there a standard search algorithm to use?**

Comment: It can be solved: $y=-W(-e^{-F(x,k)})$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I see, through the Lambert W Function. Thanks for the comment. But I am interested, as I said in the question, in ways to plot this without using The W Function, employing a numerical procedure with python.